# How to get key position from a HashMap in Java

Tags: java

How can I get the key position in the map? How can I see on which position is "Audi" and "BMW"?

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Audi", 3);
map.put("BMW", 5);
```

Comment: What do you mean by position?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As other answers state you need to use a structure like `java.util.LinkedHashMap`. LinkedHashMap maintains its keys internally using a `LinkedEntrySet`, this does not formally provide order, but iterates in the insertion order used.

If you pass the `Map.keySet()` into a List implementation you can make use of the `List.indexOf(Object)` method without having to write any of the extra code in the other answer.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Audi", 3);
map.put("BMW", 5);
map.put("Vauxhall", 7);

List<String> indexes = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet()); // <== Set to List

// BOOM !

System.out.println(indexes.indexOf("Audi"));     // ==> 0
System.out.println(indexes.indexOf("BMW"));      // ==> 1
System.out.println(indexes.indexOf("Vauxhall")); // ==> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't. From the [HashMap JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> Hash table based implementation of the Map interface. This implementation provides all of the optional map operations, and permits null values and the null key. (The HashMap class is roughly equivalent to Hashtable, except that it is unsynchronized and permits nulls.) This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

So, the order may vary between iterations. If you need to preserve the order you can take a look at `LinkedHashMap`

From the [LinkedHashMap JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html):

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So, to find the key position you basically need to iterate the keys and count the position of the key you are searching for.

On a side note, IMO this may not be the best use of the `Map` datatype. I believe that if you really need the position you should use some type of `List` (e.g. `ArrayList`) that actually preserves the order and you can use the `get` method to retrieve elements for a certain index.

Comment: Thanks. I looked here : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_linkedhashmap_class.htm but hm... it doesn't show me how i can get the position of a element. Can you give me a small example ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The keys on a Map and a HashMap are not ordered. You'll need to use a structure that preserves order, such as a [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Note that LinkedHashMap does not provide a method that gets keys by position, so this is only appropriate if you are going to be using an iterator.

The alternative is to create a second Map that maps from your key to the Integer position, and add to it as you go along:

```
Map<String, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
indexMap.put("Audi", 0);
indexMap.put("BMW", 1);
```

For a more elegant solution, you might need to give more information about what you're doing.

Comment: I have two files.In one of them i have names and in the other i have  numbers. The lines are related . If i have on the first line of the first file "John" and "1000 " on the first line of the other file, it means John has 1000$. I want to link them somehow, so i can sort them based on the numbers.