# Android get from HashMap without any loop statement

Tags: android

by this code i fill simple `HashMap` which that defined as

```
HashMap<Integer, String> complainingList = new HashMap<>();
```

fill `HashMap`

```
for (int p = 0; p < subjects.length(); p++) {
    JSONObject subject = subjects.getJSONObject(p);
    complainingList.put(subject.getInt("id"), subject.getString("title"));
}
complainingFromPostList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
adapterComplainingItems = new AdapterComplainingItems(context, complainingList);
complainingFromPostList.setAdapter(adapterComplainingItems);
```

now how can i get items without any loop statement such as `for`,`which` ?

by this code to get items i get null:

```
complainingList.get(0)
```

i want to get `id` and `title` from `0` position of hashmap, i'm using this solution on `RecyclerView` adapter

**UPDATED:**

```
public class AdapterComplainingItems extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterComplainingItems.MainViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater           inflater;
    private HashMap<Integer, String> modelList;

    public AdapterComplainingItems(Context context, HashMap<Integer, String> modelList) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    @Override
    public MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.complaining_list_items, parent, false);
        return new MainViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.complainingText.setText(modelList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    public HashMap<Integer, String> getModelList() {
        return modelList;
    }

    public void setModelList(HashMap<Integer, String> modelList) {
        this.modelList = modelList;
    }

    class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView complainingText;

        public MainViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            complainingText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.complainingText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want value of hashmap as per RecyclerView Position?

Comment: @Shashwat Gupta yes, for example: `holder.complainingText.setText(modelList.get(position));`

Comment: what is modelList here?

Comment: May be you havenot passed the instance of your hashmap to the recyclerview adapter

Comment: Is there any requirement to use only `Hashmap` ?  you can use `Arraylist` either...  you can use Arraylist of jsonObject

Comment: @Shashwat Gupta i passed that correctly and i check that on debug mode

Comment: please update your adapter code too

Comment: @Mayur Raval like with `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> lstAns = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();` ? i can't get that by this solution

Comment: @Shashwat Gupta post updated

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy, I mean like this `ArrayList<JSONObject > lstAns = new ArrayList<JSONObject >();`

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
complainingList.get(0)
```

you are trying the get the particular Hashmap key value pair where `key =0`.
I believe that you want to get the first key-value pair from a list.

Are you getting this data from some database like Firebase? **If yes, you can remove those loops using generic Types in Firebase.**

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593441/how-to-get-key-position-from-a-hashmap-in-java)

You can use a `LinkedHashMap` which basically maintains its keys internally using a LinkedEntrySet, this does not formally provide order, but iterates in the insertion order used.

And then add the data and retrieve it as given below -

```
Map<Integer, String> complainingList = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
for (int p = 0; p < subjects.length(); p++) {
JSONObject subject = subjects.getJSONObject(p);
complainingList.put(subject.getInt("id"), subject.getString("title"));
}

List<String> complainingArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(complainingList.keySet()); // <== Set to List

complainingFromPostList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
adapterComplainingItems = new AdapterComplainingItems(context, complainingArrayList);
complainingFromPostList.setAdapter(adapterComplainingItems);


System.out.println(complainingArrayList.get(0));
```

Comment: i don't know whats value of `id` or `title` on my code and i can't use your solution

Comment: I've updated the answer, please check, you don't know the key value but once you add it inside the List, you can use the properties of a List.